# Checking input in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to understand Todos example in Meteor. There's a piece of code that I can't make sense of:

```
// Returns an event map that handles the "escape" and "return" keys and
// "blur" events on a text input (given by selector) and interprets them
// as "ok" or "cancel".
var okCancelEvents = function (selector, callbacks) {
  var ok = callbacks.ok || function () {};
  var cancel = callbacks.cancel || function () {};

  var events = {};
  events['keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector] =
    function (evt) {
      if (evt.type === "keydown" && evt.which === 27) {
        // escape = cancel
        cancel.call(this, evt);

  } else if (evt.type === "keyup" && evt.which === 13 ||
             evt.type === "focusout") {
    // blur/return/enter = ok/submit if non-empty
    var value = String(evt.target.value || "");
    if (value)
      ok.call(this, value, evt);
    else
      cancel.call(this, evt);
  }
};
  return events;
};
```

What does `events['keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector] = function(){}` yield?

Why do we need to convert to string the following: `String(evt.target.value || "")`?

Does evt argument of the said function have to have .type, .target and .target.value? What I can pass in evt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've broken the question into its three parts:

**What does events['keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector] = function(){} yield?**

The `okCancelEvents` method is a way to wrap [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/keyup), [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/keydown) and [`focusout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/focusout) DOM events around a single function that curates the details of each function's outcome into a custom `ok` or `cancel` event.

This yields an [`EventMap`](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) object that is bound to the [`Template.todos.events` implementation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/todos/client/todos.js#L96) so that all `keyup`, `keydown`, and `focusout` events come through as `ok` or `cancel` via the `EventMap`.

**Why do we need to convert to string the following: String(evt.target.value || "")?**

I don't think this is necessary. `var value = evt.target.value || ""` works just as well because the browser will [interpret a string primitive as a string object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

**Does evt argument of the said function have to have .type, .target and .target.value? What I can pass in evt?**

The `evt` argument is the passed-in [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) from the `keyup`, `keydown`, and `focusout` methods and `target` and `target.value` are baked-in properties of this native `event` object. You don't need to construct this by hand.

Answer (score 4):

The `events['keyup '+selector+', keydown '+selector+', focusout '+selector] = function(){}` creates a function for meteor to map key press (keyup, keydown) events and lost focus events (focusout). This function is yielded and given to meteors template system to bind to the elements with the specific css selector.

the `evt` value contains the DOM `event` value triggered when the events are fired. The only thing that should be passed as `evt` is the original DOM `event` given when firing the event, which is given by `event` (as a variable) in the event when its triggered.

I can best explain it with code. The todos example does the same except it uses css selectors to bind events to elements:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="doSomething(event);"/>
<script>
//js code
function doSomething(evt) { console.log(evt.target.value) }
</script>
```

`String(evt.target.value || "")` basically ensures that if `evt.target.value` is a string, in case it is input as something else. Im not 100% sure when it can't be a string, but I assume browser's dont always fire events standardly.

The event isn't always needed. But its very useful. In the code sample you gave its used to identify which textbox fired the event & what keys were pressed.

More info on event:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-target
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Akshat. Too bad I can only accept one answer, b/c yours is equally good!