# Validate textarea with meteor

Tags: textarea, meteor

I use  with the event "okCancelEvents" for validating my form in meteor.

But now, I want to use a textarea. The event "ok" don't work :(

Have you an idea of event with meteor for validate textarea ? :)

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you're trying to do without any code that we can try to play around with to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the `okCancelEvents` function written in the Meteor Todos example, per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721644/checking-input-in-meteor). This function is designed to handle the events for an `<input>`, which is why its trigger for "ok/submit" is the user pressing enter (or blurring the `<input>`). See lines 59-61:

```
  } else if (evt.type === "keyup" && evt.which === 13 ||
             evt.type === "focusout") {
    // blur/return/enter = ok/submit if non-empty
```

This won't work for a `<textarea>` because as a multiline input a `<textarea>` accepts <kbd>enter</kbd> presses because that's how a user types a new line. Submitting the form based on an <kbd>enter</kbd> press would be surprising to your users, to put it mildly. The `focusout` trigger should still work fine, however.